# IE11 parent div not getting the same width as child img

Tags: html, css, width, internet-explorer-11

I'm running into a problem; I need IE11 support for *reasons*.

My parent div (and link) do not expand to the full width of my img element inside. The same thing happens if I remove the link element.

Chrome just uses the img width as the width for the link and div elements, IE uses some smaller number. That number is even smaller than the calculated width of the image.

JSfiddle (not showing error):
https://jsfiddle.net/ca0mfv21/1/

[Here's a censored image. Black is the logo itself, red is where the headline is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBdf4.png)

HTML:

```
<div class="homebar">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="homelogo">
            <a href="/mypage/index.html">
                <img src="/mypage/img/logo/mylogo.svg">
            </a>
        </div>
        <h1 id="headline"></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.homelogo {
    float: left;
    max-width:20%;
    height: 100%;
}
.homelogo a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.homelogo img {
    margin: 2em;
    height: 2em;
}
.hometitle {
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width: 60%;
}
.homebar h1 {
    float: left;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.homebar {
    height: 6em;
}
.homebar .content {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please check your code, I have created a sample using [this sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/ca0mfv21/1/), it seems that everything works well on my side, you could check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb964.png), you could try to clear the browser data (cache and history), then test it. Besides, you could also use F12 developer tools to check the CSS style, whether there have any other CSS style will cause this problem.

Comment: Thanks for checking, I just realized if I disable and re-enable my font-family style, it fixes the spacing. Might need to reevaluate my choice there.